# probability and bayes' theorem

Tags: probability

A veterinarian who specializes in large cat breeds categorizes his patients’ visits according to the primary reason for their visit.  In the past year, 10% of the cats had been diagnosed with cancer, 30% had bacterial infections, and the remaining visits were for routine vaccinations.  According to the doctor’s records, 40% of the cats with cancer died of that illness, 10% of the cats with bacterial infection died of that illness, and 1% of the cats died from adverse reactions to their vaccinations.  Given that a cat survived, what is the probability that the cat was categorized as having a bacterial infection?

P(Cancer) - 0.10, and P(Bacterial infection|Cat survived) = P(CAt survived & Bacterial infection)/P(Cat survived)

Find the percentage of cats which survived: 0.96

find the percentage of cats with a bacteria infection that survived.

Comment: This vote to close is way off here.

Comment: What is the probability that a cat survived and what is the probability of a bacterial infection?

Comment: I'm thinking Bayes theorem

Comment: It's definitely Bayes theorem.  Add more of your thoughts to your answer and you will get a response.  Add what you have done so far.

Comment: and now I think there's some conditioning needed with the numerator, and I was stuck

Comment: 1) Find the percentage of cats which survived and 2) find the percentage of cats with a bacteria infection that survived.  Here's a hint: $10\%$ of the cats had cancer and $40\%$ of them died so $0.40 * 0.10 = 0.04 = 4\%$ of them died of cancer.

Comment: @Jared, could you please start the above?

Comment: See my answer but $60\%$ of the $10\%$ diagnosed with cancer survived (that's $6\%$ of the total).  Then $90\%$ of the $30\%$ of bacterial infections survived--so $27\%$ survived of the total.  Finally $99\%$ of $60\%$ of the rest of the cats survived: $59.4\%$ of the total.  So finally you should arrive at $\frac{27}{6 + 27 + 59.4} \approx 29.22\%$.

Answer (score 1):

Given Data:

- $P(\text{cat has cancer})=\color\red{0.1}$
- $P(\text{cat with cancer dies})=\color\orange{0.4}$
- $P(\text{cat has bacterial infection})=\color\green{0.3}$
- $P(\text{cat with bacterial infection dies})=\color\purple{0.1}$
- $P(\text{cat requires routine vaccination})=\color\gray{0.6}$
- $P(\text{cat with routine vaccination dies})=\color\magenta{0.01}$

---

Let $A$ denote the event in which a cat has a bacterial infection.

Let $B$ denote the event in which a cat survives (i.e., does not die).

Then $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\color\green{0.3}\cdot(1-\color\purple{0.1})}{\color\red{0.1}\cdot(1-\color\orange{0.4})+\color\green{0.3}\cdot(1-\color\purple{0.1})+\color\gray{0.6}\cdot(1-\color\magenta{0.01})}\approx29.22\%$.

Comment: The $0.4$ is not $P(\text{cat dies from cancer})$ but $P(\text{cat dies from cancer}|\text{cat has cancer})$. From the question, with emphasis: "40% **of the cats with cancer** died of that illness".

Comment: @celtschk: You mean, I should change "cat dies from cancer" to "cat with cancer dies"?

Comment: I think you should explicitly write it as the conditional probability it is. "Cat with cancer dies" could be read as $P(\text{cat has cancer}\land \text{cat dies from cancer})$ which of course is the same as $P(\text{cat dies from cancer})$ because cats that don't have cancer don't die from it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you how to work a separate problem.

*Given that a cat died, what is the probability that it had cancer?*

We need to first calculate the probability of a cat dying.  If a cat has cancer it has a $40\%$ chance of dying, if it has a bacterial infection it has a $10\%$ chance of dying, and if it has none-of-the-above (it's just a routine vaccination) then it has a $1\%$ chance of dying.  To do that, we use the conditional probabilities given:

\begin{align}
p\left(\text{dead}\right) =&\ p\left(\text{cancer}\right)\cdot p\left(\text{dead}\ |\ \text{cancer}\right) + p\left(\text{bact}\right)\cdot p\left(\text{dead}\ |\ \text{bact}\right) + p\left(\text{vacc}\right)\cdot p\left(\text{dead}\ |\ \text{vacc}\right)\\
=&\ 0.10 \cdot 0.40 + 0.30\cdot 0.10 + 0.60\cdot 0.01 \\
=&\ 4\% + 3\% + 0.6\% \\
=&\ 7.6\%
\end{align}

The $60\%$ chance of coming for a vaccine comes from the fact that all such visits are either 1) cancer ($10\%$), 2) bacterial ($30\%$), or 3) vaccines ($100\% - 30\% - 10\% = 60\%$).

Now given that the cat died ($7.6\%$ chance) what is the probability that it had cancer?  Well $4\%$ of *all* cats had cancer *and* died, $3\%$ of *all* cats had a bacterial infection *and* died, and $0.5\%$ of *all* cats had neither but died anyway.  So it's very simple to find the probability that a cat had cancer given that it died:

$$
p\left(\text{cancer}\ |\ \text{died}\right) = \frac{4}{7.6} \approx 52.6\%
$$

Comment: Your calculations are spot on, but I find the terminology in the last paragraph problematic. “4% of dead cats have cancer” is incorrect—this states that a fraction of $\frac4{100}$ of all of the cats that died had cancer, but the correct fraction is 52.6%, as you compute soon after. It would be better to say that 4 *percentage points* out of the 7.6% of cats that died were cats that had cancer, and so on.

Comment: Yes you're right...these percentages are out of _all cats_ (living or dead).

Comment: That’s not quite it either. 10% of *all* cats had cancer, but only 4% had cancer *and* died.

Comment: Correct again, thanks for the clarification.